# Can I use $project to return a field as the top level document in a mongo aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document similar to the following, where I want to return a field of the current top level documents as the top level document itself in the results array:

```
{ 
  field1:{contents:{}}
  field2:{othercontent:{}}
}
```

I want the results of my aggregation query to return the following

```
{
  contents:{}
}
```

Can this be done with $project and the aggregation framework?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, you *can* use `$project` to do that. You just have to tell it to retrieve the nested `contents` object using [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```js
db.items.aggregate( {$project: {contents:'$field1.contents'}} );
```

Additionally, if you want to to hide the `_id` field from the output, you can specify `_id: 0` in the `$project` parameters:

```js
db.items.aggregate( {$project: {contents:'$field1.contents', _id:0}} );
```

Comment: Thanks, @w0lf.  I realize now that I didn't quite frame my question to correctly relate my problem, but your answer above is perfect for the question as written.  I've started another question to address my specific problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436510/can-i-easily-return-all-of-the-fields-of-a-subdocument-as-fields-in-the-top-leve

Comment: Small change needed in my case:
`db.items.aggregate( [ {$project: {contents:'$field1.contents'}} ] );`

Answer (score 19):

- Starting `Mongo 3.4`, the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot) aggregation operator can be used to replace a document by another (in our case by a sub-document):

  ```
  // { field1: { content: { a: 1, b: 2 } }, field2: { othercontent: {} } }
  // { field1: { content: { c: 1, d: 2 } }, field2: { othercontent: {} } }
  db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$field1" } })
  // { content: { a: 1, b: 2 } }
  // { content: { c: 1, d: 2 } }
  ```
- Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith) operator can also be used:

  ```
  db.collection.aggregate({ $replaceWith: "$field1" })
  ```